# Coping and pasting poses, not working!

Tags: armature, 3d-view, bones, pose-mode

I have a problem with my armature, so when I was trying doing a simple walk animation I did the first pose then I tried to copy the pose with control c and then on the other frame paste the pose with control shift v but it does not work. Please help me!

Comment: did you select the Bones that would be affected?

Comment: Yes, I pressed A to select all bones but it does not work... It only affects the toes after control shift v.

Comment: did you select the bones while pressing Ctrl C? Are your bone names like upperarm.L and upperarm.R?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I did not have the bones named properly! Thanks!